# Snapping line endpoints to a point feature class by adding a vertex

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcmap, editing, topology

I have a line feature class whose endpoints should snap to the closest point in a points feature class.

[image: endpoints not snapped]

The problem is, I do not want the lines to move, but rather a vertex must be added to the current endpoint and the line extended so that its new endpoint is now coincident with the point.

[image: endpoints snapped]

If I use the topology rule on the line feature class that `Endpoint must be covered by` the point feature class, the topology correction offered is to create a new point on the endpoint of the line, which I do not want. Using the `Snap` tool in the `Editing Toolbox` doesn't move anything, and anyway I do not want the positions of my lines to be changed.

Comment: What is the size of the dataset you are working with here?  Also, it is hard to tell what the actual question is here.  Are you looking for an automated solution to insert these new end vertices?  If the dataset is not too large, the simplest option may be to perform the edits by hand.  This is with the reasoning that you may spend as much time trying to find an automated solution as it would to have simply done the tedious, though relatively simple, editing by hand.

Comment: There are a few hundred lines which will need to be edited. I just thought I'd ask which methods are available besides manually inserting a vertex at each endpoint and then and extending the lines myself.

Comment: Definitely never hurts to ask.  You never know what someone may have just sitting out there.